# How to Send and receive Friend Request Programmatically in android using Parse

Tags: android, facebook, parsing

I am new to android and I am sorry if this type of question have been asked before.

Please give me an idea for sending and receiving friend request in android using `Parse`.

Although i know regarding `ParseFacebookUtils`but wanted to make such from the scratch using Parse User,Parse Query and Parser Object.

Your kind help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: What do you mean by you want to make it from scratch ?

Comment: I mean without using Facebook SDK

Comment: Not possible. you will have to use FBSDK for this.

Comment: But what if i am not taking the facebook id's, Instead cvreating the Id's on my own...?Please help

Answer (score 0):

Worked once upon a time, but not anymore. Facebook isn't going to let a device it recognizes as mobile perform this action for reasons perhaps best eluded in the entrails of wild fowl.

So your task is to not let it recognize it's coming from an android =]

Here's my hack:
[Android Facebook SDK and URL Methods form successful Friends Dialog, but cannot commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418896/android-facebook-sdk-and-url-methods-form-successful-friends-dialog-but-cannot/20435249#20435249)

best
-AnB

Comment: Also, you should remember to check with the user wrt their relationship with the person corresponding to that I'd you created; failing to do so violates fb policy and will likely cause problems for you and your users. You can check off my answer whenever you please; I doubt you'll get better until the policy changes. -AnB