# Can I add new Facebook friend without user pressing confirm button? (Android)

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I am making an Android app that allows people to add new friends when offline (users who are not connect to Internet).
And I want to automatically add these friends when users are online.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418896/android-facebook-sdk-and-url-methods-form-successful-friends-dialog-but-cannot), and it does work. But users have to press confirm button every time they add a friend, which is quite annoying.

Maybe there is a way that can press confirm button by code?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to_friend:587136133
action:add_friend
how_found:profile_button
ref_param:none
:
link_data[gt][profile_owner]:587136133
link_data[gt][ref]:timeline:timeline
outgoing_id:js_10
logging_location:
no_flyout_on_click:false
ego_log_data:
http_referer:https://www.facebook.com/
__user:100000874116873
__a:1
__dyn:7n8a9EAMCBClUSt2u5KIJeaEFoW9J6yUgByVbGAFpaBw
__req:w
fb_dtsg:AQC1l8jc
__rev:1058441
ttstamp:2658167491085610699

This is the request header for a friend request.Looking at this one,it seems they didnt expose any REST api for adding friend.It is user-actionable only.